# Else in loop not working when an invalid number is entered

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

```
System.out.println("Enter number of dice to throw, an integer [2, 10]:  ");
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in); 
n = keyboard.nextInt();

//if the input is valid
if (n>1 && n<11)
{`
    System.out.println("good");
    Random rn = new Random(); 
    int random = rn.nextInt((6-1) +1) +1; 
    System.out.println("random number is " + random); 
}     
else 
{
    //if the users input is invalid
    while (n<2 && n>10)
    {
        System.out.println("error, must be in [2,10]  ");
        n = keyboard.nextInt(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try entering a number less than 2 and greater than 10?

Comment: `while(true) {n = k.nextInt(); if (n<2 || n>10) break; System.out.println("not between 2,10, try again"); } System.out.println("good");`

Answer (score 5):

Your logic is incorrect.  The number `n` can't be less than `2` *and* greater than `10` ever.  You want less than `2` *or* greater then `10`.  Use `||` instead of `&&`.

```
while (n<2 || n>10)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the condition in the "if" statement is not met, then wouldn't the program by default go to the 'else' statement? So would you even need the while statement?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it does enter the ‘else’ but not inside the ‘while’. Because n cant be < 2 AND > 10 at the same time.

Replace

```
while (n<2 && n>10)
```

With

```
while (n<2 || n>10)
```